# How to match string in 2 diff collection and return the collection items that did not match in LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, c#-4.0, lambda

I have a 2 collection of diff types. i want to match a string in those collection and return the collection which did not match.

```
1) ac_CategoryList
2) mw_CharityList
```

would like to match if **ac_CategoryList**.Title is there in **mw_CharityList.EntryTitle**. if it is not there, than return the **ac_CategoryList** collection items which are not matched. and return one more collection of mw_CharityList type which matched in **ac_CategoryList.Title**. because i need to update the status in **mw_CharityList** collection.

```
var var charityList = _db.mw_CompetitionsEntry.Where(e => e.IsInvalid == false && e.IsPublished).ToList(); // first get the entire valid collection
var categoryList = _db.ac_Category.Where(c => c.Title != null && c.IsDeleted == false).ToList(); // get the entire valid collection

var titleNotExitsCollection = categoryList.Where(c => charityList.Any(e => e.EntryTitle.Trim() != c.Title.Trim())).ToList();
var titleExitsCollection = charityList.Where(e => categoryList.Any(c => c.Title.Trim() == e.EntryTitle.Trim())).ToList();
```

right now titleNotExitsCollection and titleExitsCollection returns the same no of records. i dont know what i am doing wrong... please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var commonTitles = categoryList.Select(x=>x.Title.Trim())
                               .Intersect(charityList.Select(x=>x.EntryTitle.Trim()));
var titleNotExitsCollection  = categoryList.Where(x=>!commonTitles.Contains(x.Title))
                                           .ToList();
var titleExitsCollection = charityList.Where(x=>commonTitles.Contains(x.EntryTitle))
                                      .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there is a not operator missing, try:

```
var titleNotExitsCollection = categoryList.Where(c => !charityList.Any(e => e.EntryTitle.Trim() == c.Title.Trim())).ToList();
```

Comment: +1 -nice and concise, tho not sure how nuuls would work if either list contained them